# Bootstrap 3 Accordion Panel Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Essentially I have a page I made in Bootstrap, where the top 60% of the page is taken up by a fluid container. I want the bottom 40% to consist of four clickable Accordion panels at 10% each.

I have set this up, but the problem is I cannot change the size of the panels. If you follow this link, you can see what I've already created.

http://bootstrapissue.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

The image below shows what I am trying to accomplish.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMGUd.png

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding some padding to the panel title might help if I understand you correctly:

```
h4.panel-title {
padding: 25px;
}
```

[It will produce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tktE.jpg)

Comment: I just asked for permission to the Google Drive file. Please let me see it.

Comment: changed link in answer